# How to avoid Memory error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04

I was running the program in Jupyter notebook.

```
    import numpy as np
    import scipy as sp
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    f=sp.fromfile(open("RSM_07_02_2019_lpf_v1"),dtype=sp.float32)
    samp_250000=f[1:350001]
    samp_250000_reshp=np.reshape(samp_250000,[7,50000])
    unit_250000=np.ones([50000,50000])
    cmul=(1/35000)*np.matmul(unit_250000,np.transpose(samp_250000_reshp))
    diff=np.transpose(samp_250000_reshp)-cmul
    cov=np.matmul(np.transpose(diff),diff)
    print(cov)
```

An error is coming when it is run

```
    MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-5-ab4aadfd66e1> in <module>()
          6 samp_250000=f[1:350001]
          7 samp_250000_reshp=np.reshape(samp_250000,[7,50000])
    ----> 8 unit_250000=np.ones([50000,50000])
          9 cmul=(1/35000)*np.matmul(unit_250000,np.transpose(samp_250000_reshp))
         10 diff=np.transpose(samp_250000_reshp)-cmul

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in ones(shape, dtype, order)
        201 
        202     """
    --> 203     a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
        204     multiarray.copyto(a, 1, casting='unsafe')
        205     return a

    MemoryError:
```

what could be the possible reasons?

Comment: Do try `free -m` command and tell the results

Comment: ______`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available` ____________________________                                                                                               `Mem:           3643        2089         323         269        1230        1023`            `____________________________  
Swap:             0           0           0`

Answer (score 1):

A tip I came across on a [Kaggle forum](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/discussion/15646)

> Just another tip, be sure if you are using ipython/jupyter notebooks,
>   make sure that the current notebook is the only running notebook.
>   Close all other applications as well.

Worked for me, I had a couple of notebooks running in the background and shutting them down cleared up enough space.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to open a "bulky" notebook is to first get rid of all `stdout` blocks in the notebook. I would do it using the following command:

```
jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --inplace example.ipynb
```

This will be relevant if you have a notebook with important information but you cannot open it. If you want to run a bulky query/command, you can increase the memory of Jupyter notebook manually in the `config`, or clear the `kernel`.